# Counter example for associativity of partially ordered sets

Tags: solution-verification, order-theory, associativity

I wasn’t convinced about the associativity property of posets, and the proof i found on math.stackexchange seemed reasonable, but still i couldnt wrap my head around it.

I tried to make a counter example, such that (x ∨ y) ∨ z ≠ x ∨ (y ∨ z)

(b ∨ c) ∨ d = h and b ∨ (c ∨ d) = i ;  in this diagram [image: this diagram]

But associativity rule says that both should be equal, i.e “h = i”.

I’m not able to figure out where im going wrong. I feel that the diagram is a poset, because it is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive, but i know it has to be wrong, otherwise it would’ve satisfied associativity.

But i cant seem to figure out why this diagram isn’t a poset and where am i going wrong. please help

Comment: What does $\vee$ mean in an arbitrary poset? It usually stands for the least upper bound, but in an arbitrary poset there need not be such a thing as a least upper bound. Do you mean a lattice?

Comment: yes, im sorry. initially i did mean a poset, but later realized the property holds true for lattices. Still even after that i wasn't able to figure out why this wasn't a lattice. Arturo's answer below has clarified my doubts! i can't have a LUB for {1,3} and {1,4}, because they have 2 upper bounds which are incomparable, and therefore the diagram is just an arbitrary poset, and not a lattice by definition, and therefore associativity need not hold true. I hope i understood it right :P

Comment: It’s not merely that they have 2 upper bounds that are incomparable (that can happen in a lattice). It’s that these two incomparable upper bounds are *minimal* upper bounds.

Comment: hey, i know this is very late, but can you give an example of a poset where there are 2 incomparable upper bounds, but the poset still qualifies as a lattice?

Comment: The 4 element lattice, $\{0,x,y,1\}$, with $x$ and $y$ in comparable. $x$ and $y$ are upper bounds for $\{0\}$, and are incomparable. And, by the way, I have a name and it’s not “hey”.

Comment: sorry about that, Arturo! Also, I get that upper bounds x and y for {0} are incomparable, but in your comment above, you mention - "It’s that these two incomparable upper bounds are minimal upper bounds". And I haven't been able to think of an example where even when there are 2 incomparable UB that are not minimal upper bounds for a pair of elements, the structure is still a lattice

Comment: Why do you need a *pair* of elements? But if you need a pair of elements, then stack two copies of the $4$ element lattice together: $0\lt x,y\lt z\lt v,w\lt 1$, with $x$ and $y$ incomparable, $v$ and $w$ incomparable. Then $v$ and $w$ are incomparable upper bound for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: ah yes! thank you once again. Im sorry if these doubts feel very trivial, but i need to get my concepts cleared before GATE (an entrance exam in India if you haven't heard of it). I'll let you know if all your help paid off :D

Comment: Hey Arturo, just wanted to let you know that I ranked 75 out of 101,922 candidates in the GATE CS entrance exam :D Although they didn't ask any question from lattices this time, still I appreciate you taking your time to solve my trivial doubts :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your partially ordered set does not have a well defined least upper bound function; that is, $\vee$ does not define an operation in your set. That’s why you are not getting equality.

For the benefit of those who don’t want to open your image, you are taking a sub-poset of the power set of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, that consists of the following sets:

- $\{1\}$
- $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{1,4\}$
- $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,3,4,5\}$, $\{1,2,3,4\}$
- $\{1,3,4,5,6\}$
- $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

You are then taking $b=\{1,2\}$, $c=\{1,3\}$, $d=\{1,4\}$.

Then the least upper bound of $b$ and $c$, $b\vee c$, is $\{1,2,3\}$; the least upper bound of $\{1,2,3\}$ and $d=\{1,4\}$, $(b\vee c)\vee d$ is $h=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

You then say that the least upper bound of $c=\{1,3\}$ and $d=\{1,4\}$ is $j=\{1,3,4,5\}$, and then taking $\{1,2\}\vee\{1,3,4,5\}$ you get $i=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

But the claim that $\{1,3\}\vee\{1,4\} = \{1,3,4,5\}$ is unwarranted. It could just as well be $h=\{1,2,3,4\}$: both $\{1,3,4,5\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ contain $\{1,3\}$ and $\{1,4\}$; and there is no strictly smaller element that contains both: you have two *incomparable* minimal upper bounds for $\{1,3\}$ and $\{1,4\}$, so you cannot even calculate $\{1,3\}\vee\{1,4\}=b\vee c$.

In general, you can’t define least upper bounds for arbitrary posets; you need more properties before the notion of $\vee$ even makes sense. Specifically, you need an [upper semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice?wprov=sfti1). What you have is a poset, but not an upper semilattice.

Comment: thanks a lot! my brain felt like it was about to explode, because i knew i wasn't seeing something that should be fairly obvious :P

Comment: @RishabhGupta: If this solves your problem, then you should “accept” the answer. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)